# FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix issue. One FacebookAppID in two Apps

Tags: ios, facebook

I've en issue with FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix. I've two apps and should use one facebookAppID for them. I've a two bundleIDs of apps in facebook dashboard and two suffix for them. In my plist file, i've suffix in url scheme

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb***********mysuffix</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

and FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix with suffix value

```
<key>FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix</key>
<string>mysuffix</string>
```

Login...Facebook screen with "You've already used the app", press confirm button and facebook shows me empty blank page and not redirected to app. When i login without suffix in my scheme all working fine. Guys, help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the following setting in your **Info.plist**?

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

And there is one difference between our plists.

I've added this to my plist settings:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Your App bundle ID</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb***********mysuffix</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```